# C and C++ interface 

Tags: c++, c, interface, wrapper

why it is much more difficult to provide wrappers in other languages to C++ code as opposed to C code ?

Comment: It's much more difficult to wrap C++ than C? [citation needed]

Comment: Hmm, this was a legitimate question, it really is much harder.  Just rubs people the wrong way, I guess.  Ask it again without the [c++] tag perhaps.

Comment: This was a legitimate question with legitimate technical reasons. To the OP: google C++ ABI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This varies significantly by the library itself and how its designed.

Speaking very generally, C++ is more complex in that it has objects, classes and interfaces, where C is primarily functions. Member functions of a class are named and called differently, so wrapping them takes a bit more work to provide equivalent names.

Once the library is wrapped to provide an equivalent interface and calling conventions are handled, the next difference is C++ allowing objects to be passed as function parameters, which may necessitate deep copies and similar. In a library taking purely pointers, for example COM, this isn't a problem (which is part of why COM is interoperable with so many languages and other systems), but handling the necessary copy code is very compiler-dependent even within C++.

Answer (score 2):

Every language has it's unique challenges when it comes to interacting with other languages.

You could consider C++ 'more difficult' in a sense due to its features that other languages don't have. Take for example multiple inheritance. This is a very tricky feature, and is one that many people simply say not to use at all. But if it is used, how would you translate that into another language?

The key point, though, is that the language itself is no more difficult to wrap - the problem is in mapping features that don't exist in other languages is darn near impossible. However, if the feature doesn't exist in that language, you have to ask yourself why it's not in there and if you should even be using it at all in the first place.

Comment: I would have given this a +1, except for `if you should even be using it at all`.  That implies that it's a useless feature of the language since other languages don't need it, instead of "if you should be using it in a wrapped interface"

Comment: @MooingDuck Well, that "if you should..." may end up evaluating to true. I wouldn't call something like multiple inheritance a useless feature, but rather an error prone feature that other languages have specifically avoided. So yes, some thought should go into whether or not you want to use features that have caused other developers headaches in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Extending somewhat upon answers given by others, another nasty issue to consider is exceptions.  There are a number of ways exceptions can be implemented in an operating system, language, or run-time library.  The way C++ implements them is in some significant ways unique.  If a C++ routine is called from another language and throws an exception, it's not entirely clear how that should be handled.  One approach would be to simply declare all such exceptions fatal.  Not unreasonable, but it prevents other languages from being used to perform what would otherwise be useful tasks.  For example, consider a routine that would enumerate through a list of items and compute the sum; if the evaluation of one of the items throws an exception, the exception should percolate up to the caller of the routine to enumerate the list.  If the routine to enumerate the list were written in another language, though, arranging for the exception to percolate up properly through the layers could be problematic.